# How do Benzodiazepines induce Rewarding (Euphoric) effects?

Tags: pharmacology, benzodiazepine

Benzodiazepines are a class of drugs that serve as positive allosteric modulators of the GABA<sub>A</sub> receptor by binding to their own "site" on the aforementioned receptor. By doing this they produce euphoria and a wide range of effects characteristic of Central Nervous System (CNS) depression (e.g. anxiolysis, sedation, amnesia, mental confusion, muscle relaxant effects).

I know that an interaction with the mesolimbic dopamine ("reward") pathway would have to come in somewhere but where? I also know that GABAergic neurons downregulate activity in the mesolimbic dopamine pathway and that this is how opioids and cannabinoids induce euphoria -- they inhibit the release of GABA from presynaptic neurons in the mesolimbic dopamine pathway. I just find that this would be confusing in the case of benzodiazepines since they increase GABA activity, presumably also in the mesolimbic dopamine pathway thus producing dysphoria and not euphoria.

**I just would like to know how they manage to induce euphoria in full (what they do to increase activity in the mesolimbic dopamine pathway that thus leads to euphoria)**

Please cite journal articles to substantiate your claims.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could you be a bit more specific about what you need to know? You seem to be giving the answer in the question.

Comment: I think it'll be clear now.

Comment: Euphoria is linked  to opioid receptors and (more recently) with the endocannabinoid system. The dopamine pathway you talk about is linked to addiction.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I read the question wrong.

Benzodiazepines do not bind to GABA<sub>A</sub> receptors universally. Thus the presumption that it inhibits the mesolimbic dopamine pathway may be wrong. They may not interact directly with said pathway at all.

Many subtypes for the GABA<sub>A</sub> receptor exist. The receptor consists of 5 subunits. The following subunits are known to exist: α1-6, β1-3 and γ1-3. The most common combination has two α, two β and one γ. You find ones with distinct compositions at distinct locations in the brain. All have two bindingsites for GABA, but only a subset has an additional binding site for benzodiazepines.

The benzodiazepine binding site is at the interface of an α and a γ subunit, so receptors without this structure will show no affinity for benzodiazepines. Additionally the α subunit must contain a histidine residue, which is only true for α1, α2, α3 and α5. That is paraphrased from wikipedia, where you can find the sources as well.

I still think you need to consider the idea that benzodiazepines may not interact directly with the dopaminergic reward pathway, like opiates and cocaine does. I attribute the euphoria to be an indirect effect, resulting from the muscle relaxation (which will feel like you had a good massage), and the calmness of the mind.